# Custom PropertyVersions for observed data

Tags: ocean, petrel

Does anyone know if it is possible to create custom property version for observed data using Ocean?

I'd like to store 2 sets of observed values based on the same template.

Cheers,

Neal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but neither Petrel nor Ocean provides this functionality. You can use the only predefined ObservedDataVersionSelection[s], the list of available options can be obtained via Petrel's import data dialog or you can retrieve it programmatically via ObservedDataSetForWell.AllObservedDataVersionSelections (Note: you can retrieve this list from any ObservedDataSetForWell, e.g. you can get it from a just created and "empty" set)

Comment: There is no "uniq" constraint for the usage of ObservedDataVersionSelection within one set: you can have as many duplicated versions ("columns") in one set as you wish but it will be difficult to maintain it, because there is no way to set/update a name (or ID) for the particular version.

Comment: As you say, it will be very difficult to distinguish between the different set of observed data if the names are the same.